# Annoying white arrows on the taskbar icons area. Windows 10

Tags: taskbar, icons, windows-10-preview

I've just installed Windows 10 Insider Preview Build 14279

And I get these annoying white bands/arrows on the taskbar icon area.

[image]

How can I get rid of them?

I've tried different options at Properties -> Notification Area -> Customize
But the white arrows are always there (If I have more than 6 icons).

How can I enlarge the area reserved to the icons?
I'd like to see all my icons at once, as before.

Some people suggests using the "Taskbar Tweaker" tool, but it doesn't work on Windows 10 Insider. In fact the webpage says it's dangerous.

Comment: Finally I had to uninstall this version of Windows 10, it has too many problems.

Answer (score 2):

This is a known [issue since Build 14271](http://winaero.com/blog/remove-arrows-from-system-tray-in-windows-10-build-14271/).

To fix the bug and remove arrows from the system tray in Windows 10 build 14271, you need to do the following:

- Right click the empty space on the taskbar to open its context menu.
- Tick the item called "Show touch keyboard button".

After you did this, the issue is gone.

See this [video for the steps](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i8b2kW5feOw).

Comment: That was the first I tried because it's said on many websites but it doesn't work. If you have more than 6 icons the arrows will remain there.

Comment: submit it to Microsoft via the feedback app.